# cannot import name 'SkipError' from 'rest_framework.exceptions'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use DRF, but it raises this error:

> raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
>
> django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template
> library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load
> 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name
> 'SkipError' from 'rest_framework.exceptions'
> (C:\Users\C.M\.virtualenvs\src-Hn7NFGL7\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\exceptions.py)

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # apps 
    'accounts',
    'home',
    'job',
    'contact',
    
    # django modules
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    
    # third-party
    'bootstrap4', 
    'cities_light',
    'django_filters',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('jobs/', include('job.urls', namespace='jobs')),
    path('contact/', include('contact.urls', namespace='contact'))
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

How can I solve the error?
I use Django 4.1 and DRF 3.14.0

Answer (score 1):

There is no module named `SkipError` in the `rest_framework.exceptions`  . **DRF's template tags will not try to import this module**. Ensure you installed the right drf and third party apps ('bootstrap4', 'cities_light', 'django_filters') in your virtual environment:

for **django-rest-framework**  : `pip install djangorestframework`

for **django-cities-light** : `pip install django-cities-light`

for **django-filter** : `pip install django-filter`

for **django-bootstrap4** : `pip install django-bootstrap4`

Comment: the error still appears, I installed all of this correctly

Answer (score 0):

The issue is version related. What you are doing is following the old procedure with new version of python. One option is try to downgrade your python's version and retry, which may solve your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).